# PowerShell: Import-CSV returning header names and brackets not in source file

Tags: powershell, csv

I'm sure this will end up being dead simple, but I can't figure it out.

I'm writing a script to read in a CSV file. I then have a loop that runs a command on the objects from the imported CSV. However, I'm getting a bunch of extraneous data that is causing me grief.

Import command:

```
$fixme = Import-Csv C:\temp\scripts\rename_script\oldname1.csv -Header OldName,NewName
```

Content of this file:

```
Computer1,Computer2
Computer3,Computer4
```

What I want to do is be able to call $fixme.OldName and $fixme.NewName. Problem is, this is the output I'm getting:

```
$fixme
@{OldName=Computer1; Newname=Computer2}
@{OldName=Computer3; Newname=Computer4}

$fixme.OldName
[nothing]

$fixme.NewName
[nothing]
```

What am I missing here?

I should also add that this is test data, I actually have several hundred lines to loop through, which I have working, it's just that for some reason I can't figure out how to pass the correct data in from this dang csv.

Answer (score 0):

So in the bottom script you didnt set **$fixme** to equal anything. You should drop those hash tables into a array

```
$fixme = @(
    @{OldName='Computer1'; Newname='Computer2'},
    @{OldName='Computer3'; Newname='Computer4'}
)

$fixme | %{ $_.oldname }

$fixme | %{ $_.newname }
```

as for the first script i was able to get it running

```
$CSV = @"
Computer1,Computer2
Computer3,Computer4
"@

$fixme = $CSV | ConvertFrom-Csv -Header OldName, NewName
$fixme.OldName
$fixme.NewName
```

Comment: It's all one script, I just broke it out that way trying to explain. The second part is all test commands after I set the value of $fixme with the import-csv command.